# Postman Mock Service CORS Issue

Tags: cors, postman

Is there a way in Postman app where you can set CORS on the server side? I want to set it to just * but I keep getting random headers coming back from the server along with this error: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values ', *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'mycoolsite' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can set any header in the response that is part of the example. In my case I left 'access-control-allow-origin' blank not realizing that it needed to be set to *. You can find the headers in the headers tab in the response. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, my solution was adding the headers:

```
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {{applicationFullURL}}
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

[image]

In the response.